# Hyperledger Fabric Set Up Docker-Compose Key Error

Tags: docker, vagrant, docker-compose, hyperledger, hyperledger-fabric

I am attempting to launch a sample hyper ledger environment with an orderer, a peer, and a ca-server.

When I issue the command docker-compose up I receive the following errors during setup:

```
peer0      | panic: Error when setting up MSP from directory /etc/hyperledger/fabric/msp/sampleconfig: err Could not load a valid signer certificate from directory /etc/hyperledger/fabric/msp/sampleconfig/signcerts, err stat /etc/hyperledger/fabric/msp/sampleconfig/signcerts: no such file or directory
```

And for the orderer:

```
orderer    | * '' has invalid keys: genesis, sbftlocal
orderer    | panic: Error unmarshaling config into struct:1 error(s) decoding:
orderer    | 
orderer    | * '' has invalid keys: genesis, sbftlocal
```

Finally the output when I check the results in another terminal, I find that only the fabric-ca-server has successfully initiated.:

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                          COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                    NAMES
d32864fd391f        hyperledger/fabric-ca:latest   "fabric-ca-server ..."   3 days ago          Up 3 days           0.0.0.0:7054->7054/tcp   ca
```

Where does this problem arise? I was told in the tutorial you do not need to set up the keys when using vagrant and docker.

Comment: Going by the error message, you haven't generated valid certificates/ they have been stored in a different location and the path you have specified is wrong. Please have a look at this: http://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started.html#run-the-tools

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error occurs when you try to start your network, i.e. when you execute the command docker-compose up.

It tries to create three Docker containers: one for the CA, another one for the orderer and a last one for the peer. However, it only create the Docker container for the CA, as we can see in your third image.

When you execute the command *docker-compose up*, you should define a configuratio file (*docker-compose-cli.yaml*). In that configuration file you define the MSP directories, i.e. the directories where you have your keys for each node. In addition to it, you should change the configuration file (*docker-compose-base.yaml*), because the first configuration file uses also this one to create each node.